# How to download this particular Google Doodle?

Tags: firefox

I have gone through the process to download the google doodle and it works for most of the doodle. However, when i am trying to use the same process (saving .mht file for offline usage in IE browser) it doesn't work for this particular doodle.

https://www.google.com/doodles/icc-champions-trophy-2017-begins

When i right click this in Firefox browser, it starts the game and doesn't let me get the Frame options. Could anyone suggest how can this doodle be saved for offline usage?

Comment: Do you want the still image (.jpg or .png) or the gif files? If you use [Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html), right click on that page and select "Download all link".

Comment: I actually want to download the whole game. Not just the images.

Comment: see this https://superuser.com/questions/459471/how-to-download-google-doodle-for-offline-usage+

Comment: @Biswa: I think you missed reading that i have already tried that post reading the solution in that question. Using that method if i do a R-Click on the doodle, it starts the game instead of giving me options for 'This Frame'.